# How can I remotely detect if a Windows server is ready for login

Tags: windows, powershell, automation

In order to build an automated deployment pipeline, I need to be able to clone and deploy Windows Server virtual machines, sysprep them, and then perform various customisation tasks on them.

Some steps, such as sysprep, require a reboot, so I currently simply wait for the reboot to happen, and once the machine comes online again I can execute the customisation on it.

The problem with this is that sysprep performs various actions after the reboot, and as far as I can tell, everything on the machine becomes available during the time when "preparing Windows" is still showing on the machine. This means I can use PowerShell Remoting to start changing things, but I don't want to do my customisations which could reboot the machine, while the first-boot stuff is still happening.

How can I remotely detect that a machine is "fully" booted, or at least past any deployment stages so it's in a state ready to log into? Is there some service that only starts when the login is available? Maybe a registry key to indicate that the boot process was completely fully?

Comment: _clone and deploy Windows Server virtual machines, sysprep them, and then perform various customisation tasks on them_ This sounds like a job for [MDT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sccm/mdt/use-the-mdt).

Comment: @BenH it really doesn't apply. In any case, "completely change your underlying environment" is rarely possible. I need an answer to the question. This might not just be for new builds. Consider any reboot after Windows updates...

Comment: One way might be to (pre-)configure eventlog forwarding and watch the central log server for related log messages.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers Not a bad idea. Even without forwarding,if there _is_ a significant eventlog entry, I can check for that with PSRemoting.

Answer (score 0):

This loop does the trick pretty well for me.

`while (-not (Test-Path \\machineName\c$)) {
      Start-Sleep 1
      Write-Host "Waiting..."
}`

From what I've experienced, the file system is accessible a couple seconds after the login screen appears, so I'd assume the system is "fully" booted.

Comment: So close. Turns out the `-Credential` parameter on `Test-Path` is not supported. I'll have to wrap it in some sort of authentication, or try to map it using New-PSDrive. Why are these things still difficult in 2018?

Comment: Maybe seems silly, but something like this?
https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/benshy/2012/06/04/using-a-powershell-script-to-run-as-a-different-user-elevate-the-process/

Comment: unfortunately, the machine that the test is running on won't be able to authenticate as the remote machine's user. I could however remote onto the target machine and test for \\localhost\c$ I guess. It's all a bit silly, so anything that works will do. Currently a sleep(60) works, but is dependent on platform load.

Answer (score 0):

make a `loop` and wait for following `registry` key to become `IMAGE_STATE_COMPLETE`

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Setup\State

IMAGE_STATE_COMPLETE represents fully completed sysprep after reboot.
```